# Libtorrent python SSL bindings

Tags: c++, python, p2p, libtorrent

Does libtorrent-python provide SSL bindings? So far it seems it does not expose SSL functionality - I found this discussion however, which mentions that SSL functionality was integrated into the Python API:
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1340755061.4fea4c75d780a%40puss.acc.umu.se&forum_name=libtorrent-discuss

Being a big fan of libtorrent this would be really sweet if its exposed on the Python layer!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

It has been in since libtorrent 0.16.2. The functions associated with SSL torrents are:

torrent_handle::set_ssl_certificate
class torrent_need_cert_alert
session_settings::ssl_listen

all of which are in that version and later.